# Hosting the django app in an nginx server

Tags: django, deployment

I have developed a django app and I want to deploy it now. My friend has a site on his own, which is an nginx server. I want to host my app as a subdomain in his site. Now I am clueless of what to do now. Hours of browsing did not help me. What is that I have to do to host my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest Django deployment with nginx server is via `gunicorn`. You can follow tutorial in [How to deploy Django Project using NGINX and gunicorn](http://tyaslab.com/how-to-deploy-django-project-using-nginx-and-gunicorn/).

Notice that server condition may differ one from another. So, trial and error is commom workaround. Have a nice try! (I usually deploy my Django projects on nginx + gunicorn too ;-).

**Domain or subdomain doesn't matter. But the subdirectory matters.**